# Route specific react-router parent components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a parent component for all my website routes `<App>` that wraps around all my routes such as `/`, `/about`, etc. It looks like:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <App>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Index} />
      <Route path="/post/:id" component={Post} />
    </App>
</BrowserRouter>
```

I also have a backend management interface, used by an Admin, that I want to have a different parent component. In the end, it would look something like:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Admin>
    <Route exact path="/admin" component={AdminIndex} />
    <Route path="/admin/posts" component={AdminPosts} />
  </Admin>
</BrowserRouter>
```

But I cannot get this working. First of all, I tried having both router rules in the `BrowserRouter` wrapped in a `div` but that ended up rendering both the `<App>` and `<Admin>` component. How can I separate them so that when the router matches routes for `<App>`, it renders that and when it matches routes for `<Admin>` it only renders those components?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/admin" component={Admin}/>
    <Route path="/" component={App}/>
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>

const App = (props) => (
  <div>
    <Route path="/post/:id" component={Post}/>
    <Route exact path="/" component={AdminIndex}/>
  </div>
);

const Admin = (props) => (
  <div>
    <Route path="/admin/posts" component={AdminPosts}/>
    <Route exact path="/admin" component={AdminIndex}/>
  </div>
);
```

If the '/admin' route is matched, the `Admin` component will be rendered exclusively, which in turn renders whatever `Route` is matched (same goes for the `App` component). For more [examples](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic).